# Prove that $b \equiv c \pmod d$ where $d=\gcd(m,n)$

Tags: modular-arithmetic

If $a \equiv b \pmod m $
 and $ a  \equiv c \pmod n$, 
Prove that $b \equiv c \pmod d$ where $d=\gcd(m,n)$

We have $a-b=km$ where $k$ is an integer 
And $a-c=ln$ where $l$ is an integer 
Now $b-c=ln-km$ 
What I need to do after this

Comment: What is MN?....

Comment: This is false as stated.  $1\equiv 3\pmod 2$ and $1\equiv 6\pmod 5$ but $3\not \equiv 6\pmod {10}$.

Comment: But how to get that?

Comment: How to get what?  The statement you want to prove is simply not true.  Perhaps you typed it incorrectly?  Or left off some important assumptions?

Comment: I typed it wrong

Comment: Ok...so, correct it.  As far as I can see, the recent edit didn't change anything.  My counterexample still holds.

Comment: @lulu is it correct now

Comment: Yes!  This version makes sense.  Write $m=dM,n=dN$ and we see that $a-b=kdM,a-c=ldN$  Subtract to see that $b-c=ldN-kdM$ and remark that $d$ divides the right hand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$(a-b=km)\wedge (b-c=\ell n)\implies a-c=km+\ell n.$$
Now by definition, the ideal $\:\bigl\{km+\ell n\mid k,\ell\in\mathbf Z\bigr\}\:$ is the ideal generated by $d=\gcd(m,n)$. Thus $a-c\in d\mathbf Z$.

Answer (score 0):

$a\equiv b\pmod m \implies a= b + pm\\
a\equiv c\pmod n \implies a= c + qn$

Setting $a= a$ gives us $b + pm = c + qn$

$b \equiv c \pmod d$ if $d|pm$ and $d|qn$